# Как игнорировать null значения в SQL запросе

Tags: java, sql, spring

Написал вот такой запрос

```
@Repository
 public interface DepositMatrixDaoInt extends JpaRepository<DepositMatrix, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  DEPOSIT_MATRIX WHERE SERVICE_PACKAGE = ?1 AND PENS_FLG = ?2 AND JOB_FLG = ?3" +
        " AND CURRENCY = ?4 AND PERIOD_FROM >= ?5 AND PERIOD_TO <= ?6 AND REFILABLE = ?7 AND WITHDRAW = ?8" +
        " AND RANGE_FROM <= ?9", nativeQuery = true)
List<DepositMatrix> sqlQuery(String service_package, String pensFlg, String jobFlg, String currency,BigInteger periodMin,
                             BigInteger periodMax, String refilable, String withdrawable, BigDecimal amount);
}
```

Здесь получаю список

```
List<DepositMatrix> depositMatrices = 
depositMatrixDaoInt.sqlQuery(servicePackage, request.getPensFlg(), 
request.getJobFlg(), currency, request.getPeriodMin(), 
request.getPeriodMax(), request.getRefilable(), 
request.getWithdrawable(), request.getAmount());
```

Возможны такие варианты, когда, например request.getAmount() == null или request.getPensFlg() == null.

Как можно исключить из SQL запроса в условии WHERE, значения request.getAmount() и request.getPensFlg(), в случае, если они равны NULL.

Comment: может добавить прямо в where `поле IS NOT NULL`. ну или для двух полей такие условия, в зависимости от требуемого результата

Comment: Можете привести пример ?

Comment: Вот, только что наконец понял, о чем на самом деле вы спрашиваете. Вам надо динамически строить сам SQL запрос, т.е. его постоянную часть загоняете в текстовую переменную, после чего if проверяете что request.getAmount() НЕ null и если это так до добавляете к строке условие "AND x=?n" (правда тут вижу у вас еще заморочки с номерами условий, значит придется в отдельной переменной вести этот номер, что бы подставить именно `?5` (например). И так же в вызов sqlQuery передавать список параметров в виде массива или еще чего то такого, смотря что готов принять sqlQuery.

Comment: ну либо в запросе писать что то вроде `AND RANGE_FROM <= ?9 OR ?9 is null`

Comment: вам возможно лучше динамически создавать `SQL` запрос, с помощью `CriteriaBuilder` например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431035/spring-jpa-repository-dynamic-query/30436524#30436524